# Accessing certain locations on a home server, hangs/times out. How can I find the cause and fix it?

Tags: performance, file-management

Accessing these locations from Windows times out or. in worse case, hangs until restarting smbd. Accessing them via SSH hangs until the connection is closed. I forcefully checked the RAID5 array where the troublesome directories are but it didn't find anything besides a lot of 'extent tree could be narrower' (which as I read is not serious).  2,5T (73%) of the array is used but I don't think it would be the issue. According to /proc/loadavg, the average system load is 6.63 7.17 6.90 which I don't think would be that big. There were no problems either until about two-three weeks ago.

I've found this in `dmesg`

```
[70920.276372] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdf] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[70920.276382] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdf] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current]
[70920.276387] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdf] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[70920.276395] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdf] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 3f 14 00 f0 00 00 f0 00
[70920.276400] print_req_error: critical medium error, dev sdf, sector 1058275568
```

How can I find out what's causing the issue and how to fix it?

Comment: could you provide ssh logs from your server?

Comment: You need to check the server logs to see what happens when you access them over ssh. There should be some indication of the problem there. Not the ssh logs (that can be useful too) but the system logs at the time you log in over ssh and do something like `ls /path/to/problematic/locations`. Does the `ls` also hang?

Comment: Next to the ssh logs, look at the smbd logs too. For a first guess: check your network config, both client and server; look at dns, routing and NTP.

Comment: @Eduardo Trápani journalctl -xe only shows a bunch of incoming connections being blocked by ufw from foreign IP address, and I don't know where to find the ssh log. Googleing it only returned results for 'listing shh login attempts' which is not good for me, since I blocked every incoming connection outside of my local network.

Comment: Try `cat /proc/mdstat` and check your array hasn't fallen apart. Check `dmesg` (or the systemd equivalent) and ensure that there are no kernel errors reported about disk access errors.

Comment: @roaima according to dmesg (https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/TXR8GYkgNC/), the problem is with one of the raid member drives.Apart from that, it show multiple connection attempts from foreign IP addresses getting blocked by UFW. So my next question is, how do I repair/remove the faulty drive from the array without having to back up my data (I don't have that much space anywhere else)? I have two spare drives already in the array, so replacing the faulty one shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: You need to provide details [in your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/588829/edit). At the moment you haven't even included the information I've asked for, so there's no way I am in a position to be able to help you. Sorry.

Comment: Ask how to replace the faulty drive as a new question (or find one of the existing questions and answers so we don't need to reject the question as a duplicate). The basic process is use mdadmi to "fail" the /dev/sdf drive, then "remove" the drive, then replace the drive. Set up the partition(s) on the new drive and then "add" the new drive.

Comment: @icarus thanks, but I already found the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to dmesg, the problem was caused by one of the member drives beginning to fail (sector fault). After removing the failing drive, the array is working normally again.